# Directly transferring a .pom file from local maven repo to remote repo

Tags: maven

I have a maven "pom-only" artifact in my local repository (which is not built by me or my company , It was an very old one ). I want to transfer this to remote repository (our companies snapshot repository) . How do i do that .
I have following in my local repo under the version folder

1. ****-1.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
2. ****-1.8-SNAPSHOT.pom.sha1

How can i push both to remote repo. One of our project is dependent on this parent/Pom only artefact ?

Answer (score 0):

The Web UI of your remote repository manager should provide functionality to upload/deploy artifacts manually. For Artifactory and Nexus I know for sure that they provide such.